# Htaccess , remove query string from 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, variables, get

Thanks in advance for the help,

I have looked around the web and stack overflow for this answer and i keep trying to implement people answers but maybe I need a direct answer to the link i want to redirect.

Im trying to get rid of the query string with the 301 redirect

**i want this url:**
/Errors/PageNotFound.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/CheeseCrisps.aspx

**to be redirected to :**
http://www.cheesesticks.com

**but my result is this url:**
http://www.cheesesticks.com/?aspxerrorpath=/CheeseCrisps.aspx

I dont want the get variables (query string) to still be on the url. I just want the new url to be cheesesticks[DOT]com

Can someone help me write the redirect code? thank you!!

here is the 301 redirect i have in place currently which i know is wrong.....
Redirect 301 /Errors/PageNotFound.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/CheeseCrisps.aspx [this is a place holder for the redirect url because stack overflow wont allow me to post more that 2 urls]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^Errors/PageNotFound\.aspx$ http://www.cheesesticks.com/? [L,R=301]
```

`/?` in the target URL will remove any existing query string.

Comment: I just added the code you gave me directly into my htaccess file with no alterations.

and the outcome is still 

http://www.cheesesticks.com/?aspxerrorpath=/CheeseCrisps.aspx

give it a try yourself :    http://www.cheesesticks.com/Errors/PageNotFound.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/CheeseCrisps.aspx

is there any other code i might be missing?

Comment: Make sure your .htaccess is enabled and this is very first rule. To verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Also did you place this .htaccess in root or in `/Errors/` folder?

Comment: the htaccess file is in the root, but the code you gave me was not at the top of the file. i can try that and the htaccess is enabled because before i posted this question i was trying different things and kept getting 500 internal errors. let me try the code at the very top of the file

Comment: THANK YOU! that worked finally! me and also my client thank you for your help! kudos